# How to detect the phone number or the Sim serial number on reading SMS using API SMSInterceptor.grabNextSMS()?

Tags: codenameone

We are using the API SMSInterceptor.grabNextSMS() to read the sms. But on dual sim we are not able to detect from which slot or number we received the SMS.

Does the API provid any other information apart from text, such as meta data or SIM serial number from which the SMS is being read.

e.g: We actually want to read SMS only from a specific number that is preregistered in our system and want to reject SMS read from any other number or slot.

Can you provide any pointers to achieve this. Of it provides any meta data line slot number of SIM serial number on phone number we can then apply some logic to achieve our requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. We use [SmsMessage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html) [here](https://github.com/codenameone/SMSActivation/blob/master/native/android/com/codename1/sms/intercept/SMSListener.java) to parse the message content and it doesn't seem to contain the number to which the SMS was sent.

However, you can encode that number into the message body so besides the activation code you would also have the number and you can parse the whole thing. For that just use your own [native interface](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) directly rather that using the cn1lib.